# Tuple set expression for division

Tags: tuples, mdx

Just trying to divide one column by the other... how to I write this expression?  I get the "fuction expects a tuple set expression for the 3 argument.  A string or numeric expression was used", which was my attempt at simply adding "/".

I tried to post pictures, but I don't have enough rep points...

Comment: this is a standard error - please add in at least the line of code with the "/" in it...

Answer (score 0):

This is ok:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[someDivision] AS
    [Measures].[x] / [Measures].[y]
...
```

It is ok because `x` and `y` are both numeric (well - usually they are)

This is not ok:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[someDivision] AS
    [Measures].[x] / [Country].[USA]
...
```

Because this is a member - `[Country].[USA]`. Could probably put braces around the USA to make it a `tuple` and hence numeric:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[someDivision] AS
    [Measures].[x] / ([Country].[USA])
...
```